# How do I test the ROS version in Python code?

Tags: ros, python, rospy, rosversion, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked for C++ (http://answers.ros.org/question/9562/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-c-code/) but it would be good to know what the correct way to do this is in Python.

There is a python script called rosversion which does this in a bit of an awkward way IMO. It does it by checking whether the "ROS_DISTRO" environment variable exists and, if not, it parses an XML file (roscore.xml). This seems quite complicated and it only gives you the release name (cturtle, electric, fuerte, etc.).

Is there a way to get access to those nice looking DEFINES like in the C++ code? Even having just the functionality of the rosversion script somewhere in an official ROS Python API function would be better than nothing (just getting the release name).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36485/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-python-code?/) by [StFS](https://answers.ros.org/users/2394/stfs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 182 on 2012-06-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look further down in `rosversion`, it only prints the distro name when invoked with the `-d` or `--distro` option. To get the ROS version string, invoke:

```
$ rosversion ros
```

On Fuerte, that returns 1.8.7 (without a newline), on Electric 1.6.9 (with a newline).

From a Python script, you can do that yourself:

```
import rospkg
version = rospkg.RosStack().get_stack_version('ros')
```

That uses the new distro-independent rospkg module. Get it like this:

```
sudo pip install -U rospkg
```

It works for other stacks, as well:

```
messages_version = rospkg.RosStack().get_stack_version('common_msgs')
```

**In most cases, it is better to test for the existence of some new API instead:**

```
TimeReference = None
try:
    from sensor_msgs.msg import TimeReference
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then, make your logic dependent on the existence of that message:

```
if TimeReference:
    tr_pub = rospy.Publisher('gps_time', TimeReference)
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4